# Creating Windows 8.1 system image error

Tags: backup, system-restore, windows-8.1

I'm experiencing "not enough space" error when trying to create system image to a USB hard drive:

> *Detailed error: ERROR - A Volume Shadow Copy Service operation error
>   has occurred: (0x8004231f) Insufficient storage available to create
>   either the shadow copy storage file or other shadow copy data.*

Blah, blah...

> *There is not enough disk space to create the volume shadow copy on the storage location. Make sure that, for all volumes  to be backup
>   up, the minimum required disk space for shadow copy creation is
>   available. This applies to both the backup  storage destination and
>   volumes included in the backup. Minimum requirement: For volumes less
>   than 500 megabytes, the minimum is 50 megabytes of free space. For
>   volumes more than 500 megabytes, the minimum is 320 megabytes of free
>   space. Recommended: At least 1 gigabyte of free disk space on each
>   volume if volume size is more than 1 gigabyte. ERROR - A Volume Shadow
>   Copy Service operation error has occurred: (0x8004231f) Insufficient
>   storage available to create either the shadow copy storage file or
>   other shadow copy data.*

I'd tried both - PowerShell

> wbAdmin start backup -backupTarget:E: -include:C: -allCritical -quiet

and via Control Panel -> File History button

Clearly both EFI and Windows Recovery Environment partitions don't meet requirements coming from System Image tool (pic below)

[image]

On top of that all system partitions are now shown as 100% free in Disk Management, it's disturbing but far from the actual state.

[image]

My question is - hot to create System Image in Windows 8.1?

Comment: I also asked the question on MS community: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-system/windows-81-system-image-problem-not-able-to-create/f0bad7b1-04a1-4b68-a2bf-4574b1361923

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out the solution is to **just back up the C drive** (without the -AllCritical option).  See the full answer here: https://superuser.com/a/665098/265945