# Windows 8.1 Insufficient storage available for backup

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, windows-home-server

I'm using Windows Home server 2011 to backup my laptop, but I have been unable to perform a backup since upgrading to Windows 8.1. I get an "Insufficient storage available for backup. The C drive on my laptop has ~52GB of free space. The System Reserved volume has only 8.77MB of free space though. My desktop computer, which I can back up successfully, has 46MB free on the System Volume.

[image: Backup Error]

I found this related question: [Windows 8.1 Insufficient storage available to create shadow copy](https://superuser.com/q/663782/96231), however the only volume shadow copies that are on the hard disk are for the C drive, not the System Reserved volume., so I don't think that deleting the existing shadow copies will solve the problem.
[image: vssadmin output]

Comment: Does it work if you try to backup to another target instead of the HS2011 box (like say, a USB drive, or a share on another computer)?

Comment: No it doesn't, I get the a "There is not enough disk space to create the volume shadow copy on the storage location." The full error message can be seen here: http://static.raymond.cc/images/windows7-the-backup-failed.png

Comment: @cmorse did you ever figure this out? I'm having the same issue, just started after I moved to Windows 8.1.

Comment: @cmorse Not sure if this is a valid work around for you or not, but I just removed the 0.3GB partition from the list of drives to be backed up and it seems to work fine now.

Comment: @GotDibbs: I would prefer to back up both partitions to simplify restoring the machine. I never did figure out a fix though.