# Backup system image Windows 8.1 fails

Tags: backup, windows-8.1

I have read this topic:
[Windows 8.1 Insufficient storage available to create shadow copy](https://superuser.com/questions/663782/windows-8-1-insufficient-storage-available-to-create-shadow-copy)

And started an administrator prompt and:

> wbadmin start backup -backuptarget:e: -include:c:

and got this output:

> Creating a backup of volume (C:), copied (60%).
>   The backup of volume (C:) could not be completed. Error: De back-up is mislukt o
>   mdat een shaduwkopie op het bronvolume is verwijderd. Dit kan zijn veroorzaakt d
>   oor veel schrijfactiviteit op het volume. Probeer de back-up opnieuw uit te voer
>   en. Als het probleem zich blijft voordoen, kunt u wellicht de opslagruimte voor
>   schaduwkopieën uitbreiden met de opdracht VSSADMIN Resize ShadowStorage.
>
> ### Summary of the backup operation:
>
> The backup operation stopped before completing.
>   The backup operation stopped before completing.
>   Log of files successfully backed up:
>   C:\WINDOWS\Logs\WindowsBackup\Backup-02-04-2014_09-06-42.log
>
> Log of files for which backup failed:
>   C:\WINDOWS\Logs\WindowsBackup\Backup_Error-02-04-2014_09-06-42.log
>
> De back-up is mislukt omdat een shaduwkopie op het bronvolume is verwijderd. Dit
>    kan zijn veroorzaakt door veel schrijfactiviteit op het volume. Probeer de back
>   -up opnieuw uit te voeren. Als het probleem zich blijft voordoen, kunt u wellich
>   t de opslagruimte voor schaduwkopieën uitbreiden met de opdracht VSSADMIN Resize
>    ShadowStorage.

Opening the log gave me the same info as in the output of the wbadmin.

> C:\WINDOWS\system32>notepad C:\WINDOWS\Logs\WindowsBackup\Backup_Error-02-04-201
>   4_09-06-42.log

This is my diskmanager:
[image]

so all partitions have sufficient free space. vssadmin resize shadowstorage did not work and removing the shadow does not work either.

This is the storage list:

> C:>vssadmin list shadowstorage
>   vssadmin 1.1 - Volume Shadow Copy Service administrative command-line tool
>   (C) Copyright 2001-2013 Microsoft Corp.
>
> Shadow Copy Storage association
>      For volume: (E:)\?\Volume{90664127-73bc-11e3-bed1-005056c00008}\
>      Shadow Copy Storage volume: (E:)\?\Volume{90664127-73bc-11e3-bed1-005056c000
>   08}\
>      Used Shadow Copy Storage space: 0 bytes (0%)
>      Allocated Shadow Copy Storage space: 0 bytes (0%)
>      Maximum Shadow Copy Storage space: 279 GB (15%)

I have ran a bitdefender full scan yesterday which took several hours (over 5) and if I use the GUI, I always get 0x80780169

[image]

ps. sorry for the dutch parts, but I'd rather have an exact output copy then a false translation

**edit** I found an article online about a timeout. I have set the value of the service in the register (regedit) but did not solve it.

**edit2** I am decrypting my drive:
[image: my c drive]

**edit3** making a sys image backup with an unencrypted drive did not work. also when I rebooted the pc. Turned bitlocker back on because of security (obvious) still no solution.
still have 0x80780169 in my eventvwr

Perhaps it is just this bug in windows: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-system/cant-backup-81-using-system-image-backup-error/90e39029-ff0d-4318-8701-5f7078198cd0

any thoughts on that before I start the 13!! steps...

to prove that seany is wrong and that there still is an option to make a win8 full img backup: (bottom left) sorry for dutch screenshot btw

[image]

Comment: Just to make it clear to others, you are trying to create a backup image of your system drive C onto drive E, is that correct? There has to be something in the log file other then "The backup operation stopped before completing".  It looks like you have bitlocker enabled is that the case?

Comment: Yes I have bitlocker enabled on my C drive and about the log: I am sorry, but the content was limited to the exact same error message above. No file mention or whatsoever.

Comment: I highly suspect this problem is connected to Bitlocker.

Comment: can I verify that it is bitlocker related and how can I fix it without disabling bitlocker?

Comment: I know of no way to confirm bit locker is the cause if disabling bit locker isn't an option

Comment: Because it took me ages to enable it ;-)

Comment: See if in the Event Viewer you have a useful error message when the backup fails. I also do not counsel using Windows Backup - too many gotchas. Are you interested in alternatives?

Comment: English translation: "Backup failed as shadow copy on source volume got deleted. This might caused by high write activity on the volume. Please retry the backup. If the issue persists consider increasing shadow copy storage using 'VSSADMIN Resize ShadowStorage' command.
Error code: 0x80780169"